# The database owner SID recorded in the master database differs from the database owner SID

Tags: sql-server, clrstoredprocedure, tsqlt

When I try to install tSQLt onto an existing database i get the following error:

> The database owner SID recorded in the master database differs from
>   the database owner SID recorded in database ''. You should correct
>   this situation by resetting the owner of database '' using the ALTER
>   AUTHORIZATION statement.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

This problem can arise when a database restored from a backup and the SID of the database owner does not match the owners SID listed in the master database.  Here is a solution that uses the "ALTER AUTHORIZATION" statement recommended in the error message:

```
DECLARE @Command VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[<<DatabaseName>>] TO 
[<<LoginName>>]' 

SELECT @Command = REPLACE(REPLACE(@Command 
            , '<<DatabaseName>>', SD.Name)
            , '<<LoginName>>', SL.Name)
FROM master..sysdatabases SD 
JOIN master..syslogins SL ON  SD.SID = SL.SID
WHERE  SD.Name = DB_NAME()

PRINT @Command
EXEC(@Command)
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems more appropriate. Do you think it's not worthwhile to use quotename() instead of putting the '[' in the string? Also maybe selecting into var  DBName and var LoginName then putting those together into var Command instead of using REPLACE()?

Comment: If you have spaces or special characters like '-' in your DB name this script will give you error. So just put [] brackets like this: 'ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[<<DatabaseName>>] TO [<<LoginName>>]'

Comment: When I run this I get the error "The proposed new database owner is already a user or aliased in the database"

Comment: For this script, the inner join to syslogins does not work for me probably because the SID mismatch _is_ the problem.

Answer (score 34):

Added this to the top of the tSQLt.class.sql script

```
declare @user varchar(50)
SELECT  @user = quotename(SL.Name)
  FROM  master..sysdatabases SD inner join master..syslogins SL
    on  SD.SID = SL.SID
 Where  SD.Name = DB_NAME()
exec('exec sp_changedbowner ' + @user)
```

Comment: This worked like a charm with `tSQLt Version: 1.0.5873.27393` and appears to be a simpler solution. Using MS SQL Server 2019 Developer and SSMS 18.

Comment: Very simple and nice. Had this issue when restoring to a new server from backup and then trying to add an assembly.

Answer (score 23):

Apply the below script on database you get the error:

```
EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa'

ALTER DATABASE [database_name] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
```

Comment: The second statement cases the following security vulnerability: VA1102 - The Trustworthy bit should be disabled on all databases except MSDB

Answer (score 6):

Necromaning:
If you don't want to use the SQL-Server 2000 views (deprecated), use this:

```
-- Restore sid when db restored from backup... 
DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @Command = N'ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::<<DatabaseName>> TO <<LoginName>>' 
SELECT @Command = REPLACE 
                  ( 
                      REPLACE(@Command, N'<<DatabaseName>>', QUOTENAME(SD.Name)) 
                      , N'<<LoginName>>' 
                      ,
                      QUOTENAME
                      (
                          COALESCE
                          (
                               SL.name 
                              ,(SELECT TOP 1 name FROM sys.server_principals WHERE type_desc = 'SQL_LOGIN' AND is_disabled = 'false' ORDER BY principal_id ASC )
                          )
                      )
                  ) 
FROM sys.databases AS SD
LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals  AS SL 
    ON SL.SID = SD.owner_sid 


WHERE SD.Name = DB_NAME() 

PRINT @command 
EXECUTE(@command) 
GO
```

Also prevents bug on oddly named database or user, and also fixes bug if no user is associated (uses sa login).

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to change DB owner is:

```
EXEC SP_ChangeDBOwner 'sa'
```

Comment: Yes we have established that.