# Installing microsoftml and revoscalepy for SQL Machine Learning

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, revoscalepy

I'm trying to install `microsoftml` and `revoscalepy`. These packages are developed by microsoft and can be used (apparently) for scoring python models in `SQL server 2017`.

I'm using an anaconda environment with python 3.7 installed.

The intuitive does not work:

```
pip install microsoftml
pip install revoscalepy
```

*Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement microsoftml*

The syntax of the [docs](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningSamples-mml) also gives me an error

```
pip install https://rserverdistribution.azureedge.net/production/revoscalepy/9.2.1/wb/1033/d282048eb04046999211535f7368a0a4/windows/microsoftml-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

*Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement revoscalepy*

Would appreciate any other suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a bit of time to understand, so here I will try to explain my findings. Also check the full [docs](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/install/sql-machine-learning-services-windows-install?view=sql-server-2017).

- `microsoftml` and `revoscalepy` are not on `PyPi`, so you can not `pip install` them. Rather they are included in a full `python 3.5` distribution provided by Microsoft. It is a shame they don't support >= 3.6.
- You can install this either when installing `Microsoft SQL Server 2017` (or beyond). This is generally what you want to do if you want to use it in SQL.
- Or you can install the seperate dist by installing it [yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/install/machine-learning-server-windows-install). I personally used this when developing code on a different machine than the database.

**SQL server tips**

- Make sure the so-called launchpad is on - see [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4558/sql-server-launchpad-service-cannot-be-started/).
- Make sure you executed (in SQL) `sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1`
- Make sure you executed (in SQL) `sp_configure 'external scripts enabled', 1; RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;`
- Make sure you enabled the scoring mechanism on the SQL database. See this part of the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/real-time-scoring?view=sql-server-2017#bkmk_enableRtScoring).
- If you cannot assign users to the scoring role, see this [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389656/the-database-owner-sid-recorded-in-the-master-database-differs-from-the-database).
- For me this was the folder `F:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES`
- Help your python developers by directly registering a jupyter kernel `cd folder & python.exe –m ipykernel install –name “Py35 SQL”`

**Separate installation tips**

- Follow the steps outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/install/machine-learning-server-windows-install), and NOT the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/install/python-libraries-interpreter).
- For me this was the installation folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ML Server\PYTHON_SERVER`
- Help your python developers by directly registering a jupyter kernel `cd folder & python.exe –m ipykernel install –name “Py35 SQL”`

Answer (score 0):

As a novice user of these SQL 2017 packages, I found Microsoft's documentation at the link below most helpful: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/install/sql-machine-learning-services-windows-install?view=sql-server-2017

I was able to successfully setup and run some revoscalepy and microsoftml samples on my Windows 10 machine. I used Python 3.5.