# The database owner SID recorded error when Integrated security= true;

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net, sql-server-2017

I have a C# application which creates a database, tables using T-SQL code executed by `SqlCommand` class.

Some scripts which are executed by `SqlCommand`:

```
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
exec sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
RECONFIGURE;   

use FooDatabase;

if exists (select * from sys.objects where name = 'CreateLineString')
    drop aggregate dbo.CreateLineString;

if exists (select * from sys.objects where name = 'GeographyUnion')
    drop aggregate dbo.GeographyUnion;

if exists (select * from sys.objects where name = 'ConvertToPolygon')
    drop function dbo.ConvertToPolygon;

if exists (select * from sys.assemblies where name = 'osm2mssqlSqlExtension')
    drop assembly osm2mssqlSqlExtension;

create assembly osm2mssqlSqlExtension FROM 0x4D5A900 /* some numbers more here ...*/ 
300000 WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;

GO

create aggregate dbo.CreateLineString(@lat float,@lon float,@sort int) returns geography
external name osm2mssqlSqlExtension.[OsmImporter.DbExtensions.LineStringBuilder];
GO 
create aggregate dbo.GeographyUnion(@geo geography) returns geography
external name osm2mssqlSqlExtension.[OsmImporter.DbExtensions.GeographyUnion];
GO 
create function dbo.ConvertToPolygon(@geo geography) returns geography
as external name [osm2mssqlSqlExtension].[OsmImporter.DbExtensions.Functions].ConvertToPolygon;
GO
```

C# code to execute the above sql code:

```
protected void ExecuteSqlCmd(string sqlCommand)
{
    var sqlCommands = sqlCommand.Split(
        new[]
        {
            "GO"
        }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var connString = Connection.ToString();
    using (var con = new SqlConnection() { ConnectionString = Connection.ToString() })
    {
        foreach (var sql in sqlCommands)
        {
             con.Open();   
             using (var cmd = new SqlCommand() { Connection = con })
             {
                 cmd.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue;
                 cmd.CommandText = sql;
                 try
                 {
                     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                        throw;
                 }
             }
             con.Close();
         }   
     }   
}
```

When I use the following connection string:

```
"Data Source=SQL100;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True"
```

Then I see the following error:

> The database owner SID recorded in the master database differs from
>   the database owner SID recorded in database 'FooDatabase'. You should
>   correct this situation by resetting the owner of database
>   'FooDatabase' using the ALTER AUTHORIZATION statement. Configuration
>   option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. Run the
>   RECONFIGURE statement to install. Configuration option 'clr enabled'
>   changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install. Changed
>   database context to 'FooDatabase'.

If I use the following connection string, there is no error:

```
"Data Source=SQL100;Initial Catalog=;User ID=foouser;Password=foopassword
```

What am I doing wrong? How is it possible to solve this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to [use the accepted answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389656/the-database-owner-sid-recorded-in-the-master-database-differs-from-the-database), however I see the following error:

> The proposed new database owner is already a user or aliased in the
>   database. The database owner SID recorded in the master database
>   differs from the database owner SID recorded in database
>   'FooDatabase'. You should correct this situation by resetting the
>   owner of database 'FooDatabase' using the ALTER AUTHORIZATION
>   statement. Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1
>   to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install. Configuration option
>   'clr enabled' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to
>   install. Changed database context to 'FooDatabase'.

Comment: I tried reproducing your error but I can't. I seem to be missing one of the steps you are doing. I think you should amend your post describing your setup in more detail, including some c# code and when this is fired. Otherwise we all will keep guessing. For example, the answer provided by @Bibin is only adressing the possible scenario when you try to overwrite your c# created database with another backup (incl different used SIDs).

Comment: @Thailo please, see my updated question

Comment: USE [FooDatabase]
GO
    -- Option #1
    EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa'
    GO

    -- OR--

    -- Option #2
    ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[FooDatabase] TO [sa]
    GO

Comment: You just execute this in your sql sever query .And connected this connection string "Data Source=SQL100;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the reason why this error is occurred. However, the solution was found. [Thanks to this great article!](https://subhrosaha.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/sql-server-error-the-proposed-new-database-owner-is-already-a-user-or-aliased-in-the-database/). It was necessary to recreate user in newly created database.

The  whole code looks likes this:

```
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
exec sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
RECONFIGURE;   

use FooDatabase;

DECLARE @user NVARCHAR(max);
SELECT @user = SL.Name
FROM master..sysdatabases SD 
JOIN master..syslogins SL ON  SD.SID = SL.SID
WHERE  SD.Name = DB_NAME()    

IF ((SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = @user) = 1)
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_dropuser @user
END 

DECLARE @Command VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[<<DatabaseName>>] TO 
[<<LoginName>>]' 

SELECT @Command = REPLACE(REPLACE(@Command 
            , '<<DatabaseName>>', SD.Name)
            , '<<LoginName>>', SL.Name)
FROM master..sysdatabases SD 
JOIN master..syslogins SL ON  SD.SID = SL.SID
WHERE  SD.Name = 'FooDatabase'
EXEC(@Command)    


create assembly osm2mssqlSqlExtension FROM 0x4D5A900 /* some numbers more here ...*/ 
300000 WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
/* The other code is omitted for the brevity */
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem can arise when a database restored from a backup and the SID of the database owner does not match the owners SID listed in the master database.Try This One

```
DECLARE @Cmd VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[<<DatabaseName>>] TO 
[<<LoginName>>]' 

SELECT @Cmd = REPLACE(REPLACE(@Cmd 
            , '<<DatabaseName>>', SD.Name)
            , '<<LoginName>>', SL.Name)
FROM master..sysdatabases SD 
JOIN master..syslogins SL ON  SD.SID = SL.SID
WHERE  SD.Name = DB_NAME()

PRINT @Cmd 
EXEC(@Cmd)
```

OR

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO


    -- Option #1
    EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa'
    GO

    -- OR--

    -- Option #2
    ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[DatabaseName] TO [sa]
    GO
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But the first my action when I see the above error is to execute this code. However, it throws another error.

Comment: I've added an error to my updated question. Please, see my updated question. I believe it is enough information.

Comment: I've found a solution. Thanks for your efforts. It was helpful, however I needed to add some code to your solution. I upvoted. Thanks a lot, man!:)